# Bring data (direct query mode) to Power BI from Databricks SQL query

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi, databricks

I have some tables and a transformation query in databricks. My task is to import databricks` query output to PowerBI in direct query mode.

Why direct?

- If any table in query is update, it should affect data on power bi site

[image]
I have tried to use direct query in power bi. But when I update transformation tables in databricks and refresh view in PowerBI, changes didn't show up

Is there any work around to get data from databrick query to PowerBI in nearly real time? At least direct query mode?

Comment: What do you mean "source as SQL script"? Power BI has a dedicated connector for Databricks / Azure Databricks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way using Partner connect in databricks premium itself. Basically you can create view for select query and using partner power bi connector you can import it in direct query mode.

> [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S3tAo5ZdeQ) video shows how to use partner connect.